# Deploying impure Python packages to AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I am interested in using a Python package ([graphviz](http://graphviz.org)) to do some back-end computing on a Flask server hosted on AWS.  This package seems to have quite a few non-Python dependencies, and indeed it cannot be installed entirely by pip.  (I installed it locally using Homebrew.)

How can I deploy a package like this to my Elastic Beanstalk environment?

With all of the other Python packages that I'm using I have just kept a list in my requirements.txt document and Elastic Beanstalk installs them automatically using pip, but this won't work with the non-Python parts of the package (mostly compiled C code, as I understand it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include, for example:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    graphviz: []            # [] can optionally be replaced with version number
    other_dependencies: []  # otherwise [] will install the latest version
```

in a `.config` file in your application's `.ebextensions/` directory. When the application is deployed using `eb deploy` the packages will be installed by the `yum` utility to your instance.

The full file will look something like (assuming you've created it using one of AWS' tutorials)

```
option_settings:
  things

container_commands:
  things

packages: 
  yum:
    graphviz: []
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to migrate to CodeDeploy, you can install Homebrew and install the packages as part of your deployments.